# What should be my app category in admob?

Tags: android, admob

I have developed an android app which is 100% educational. And now I am integrating `admob` ads to it. But in the `admob` settings, I didn't find any category named `education`. So I selected `tools` as category. But admob is showing ads according to category. And now my app is showing irrelevant ads which are not educational in category.

What can I do now? Why admob didn't include `education` in their category? Or what would be the most close category for me to suit with my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **Games: Brains & puzzles** or **Entertainment** as I see these two most suitable for educational apps.

and please beware of new google's policy &

> Collecting information from kids apps is not just considered spamming,
>   Its illegal.